# entityに紐づかないvalue objectというのはありですか?

Tags: ドメイン駆動設計

いくつか本や記事を読んでみましたがどのvalue objectもentityに入ってるものしかありません。
entityに入ってないけどvalue objetcとして定義してapplication serviceから直接呼ぶだけというパターンもありでしょうか。
もしそうなるパターンがある場合はモデリングに問題がありますか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

書籍 [エリック・エヴァンスのドメイン駆動設計](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798126708)の"値オブジェクト(VALUE OBJECTS)"節 p.97 では次のように書かれています:

> **値オブジェクト**は、しばしば、オブジェクト間のメッセージでパラメータとして渡される。一過性のことも多く、操作のために生成されては破棄される。また、**エンティティ**(および他の**値オブジェクト**)の属性としても使用される。

"application serviceから直接呼ぶだけ"というのがどういうことを指しているのかが私には明確に捉えられていませんが、値オブジェクトが必ず何らかのエンティティと関連しているべきか、という点については、Noで、特にそのような制約は設けられていません。

Comment: なるほど! ありがとうございます!